# es6 declare a variable inside an IF ( like es5 )

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

OK, this has reached a point where I am annoyed and was not able to solve this.

In ES5 I would frequently do something like...

```
if( (users = resp.results) && users.length > 0 ) {
    // do something with users
}
```

**For a moment, let's forget about the scoping and the implication and all of that...**

Babel does not like this syntax anymore starting ES6 nor does the Chrome console.

Is there an equivalent syntax now in ES6?

Comment: Chrome console has absolutely no problem with this...

Comment: Well sorry, I lied! the chrome console does work but that is because it supports es5 + es6. At least that is my assumption.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ES5/ES6. It's 'use strict', which Babel forces you to use which doesn't allow undeclared variables to be set. So... you can't do `a = 1`, you have to do `var a = 1`

Comment: ah i see ok, gotcha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to be valid when using `'use strict'`, which Babel enforces, you need to declare `users` first. If you are not using Babel or 'use strict' your original code will work just fine.

```
var users;
if( (users = resp.results) && users.length > 0 ) {
    // do something with users
}
```

will work with `'use strict'`.

You could also manually remove `'use strict'` from the top of your converted babel code if you want to continue using this trick.

Comment: so the trick is that I do not want to define users first, I would like it to be defined in the if condition

Comment: I did try your suggestion it only works if I pre-define the variable

Comment: @AssafMoldavsky what you want is impossible with 'use strict' on. Assuming you are using Babel you could manually remove the 'use strict' at the top of your converted code and what you want will work.

Comment: I see your point, I got it,  I was thinking that in ES6 this type of syntax was not possible anymore